# How to compile neutralinojs project in a way that people can open it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, neutralinojs

to open neutralino file on windows you'll need to write this:
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy"
in the cmd.
My question is: how to make the project executable even if you are not writing this long thing in the cmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the steps in [Your First Neutralinojs App](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/getting-started/your-first-neutralinojs-app), you will have an executable found at `<some-location>/myapp/dist/myapp/myapp-win.exe`. You can click on this, or create a shortcut to it, so you won't have to write a command line argument.

Comment: This does require the .dll though, isn't?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in cmd to build an executable:
`neu build`

That will create an exe in a dist folder within your project directory.